# Returning an EF model class

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I can successfully return a model from my controller like this:

```
return View(lemonadedb.Messages.ToList() );
```

It's interpreted perfectly by my view.

Now I only want to show the messages where Messages.user == Membership.GetUser().ToString().

But when I do this:

```
return View(lemonadedb.Messages.Where( p => p.user == Membership.GetUser().ToString()).ToList());
```

I get:

> 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize
>   the method 'System.String ToString()'
>   method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.'

I need some way to narrow down the results of the messages table.

Should I use the find() method somehow? I thought it was only for ID's.

How should I do this?

Comment: Shoot ... I just realized it isn't easy to return and handle multiple models. I guess I should use a ViewData mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're having this issue is that Entity Framework is trying to evaluate the expression `Membership.GetUser().ToString()` into an SQL query. You need to create a new variable to store the value of this expression and pass it into your query. Entity Framework will then just interpret this as you expect.

The following should work:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser().ToString();
return View(lemonadedb.Messages.Where(p => p.user == user).ToList());
```

I suspect this is a very common mistake that people make when writing Entity Framework queries.